# Updating variable after click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On click of and `li`, I want to get the `data-currency` and assign it to a `var`. To do this, I have the following:

```js
$(function(){

  var $currency = "€";

  $('.pricingTable__dropdown-li').click(function(){
    var data_currency = $(this).attr('data-currency');
    if(data_currency == "pounds"){
      $currency = "£";
    } else if (data_currency == "dollars") {
      $currency = "$";
    } else{
      $currency = "€";
    }
  });

  console.log($currency);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="pricingTable__dropdown-ul">
  <li data-currency="euros" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">€ Euro</li>
  <li data-currency="pounds" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">£ Pound</li>
  <li data-currency="dollars" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">$ Dollar</li>
</ul>
```

Upon refreshing my page and checking console, I see `€`. Then, when selecting another `li`, I expect to see `$currency` variable to update, but it doesn't?

Comment: You just need to move your `console.log` inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

You have to log again inside your click handler.

```js
$(function(){

  var $currency = "€";

  $('.pricingTable__dropdown-li').click(function(){
    var data_currency = $(this).attr('data-currency');
    if(data_currency == "pounds"){
      $currency = "£";
    } else if (data_currency == "dollars") {
      $currency = "$";
    } else{
      $currency = "€";
    }
    console.log($currency)
  });

  console.log($currency);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="pricingTable__dropdown-ul">
  <li data-currency="euros" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">€ Euro</li>
  <li data-currency="pounds" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">£ Pound</li>
  <li data-currency="dollars" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">$ Dollar</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, you are just not logging the variable value after changing it.

By the way, you can improve your code by using a single event listener and by accessing your data attribute using `dataset` property as follows:

```js
(() => {
  const parent = document.getElementsByClassName('pricingTable__dropdown-ul')[0];
  
  let currency = '€';
  
  const handler = (e) => {
    var data_currency = e.target.dataset.currency;
    
    if(data_currency === 'pounds') {
      currency = '£';
    } else if (data_currency === 'dollars') {
      currency = '$';
    } else {
      currency = '€';
    }
    
    console.log(currency);
  };

  parent.addEventListener('click', handler);

  console.log(currency);
})();
```

```html
<ul class="pricingTable__dropdown-ul">
  <li data-currency="euros" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">€ Euro</li>
  <li data-currency="pounds" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">£ Pound</li>
  <li data-currency="dollars" class="pricingTable__dropdown-li">$ Dollar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There already was just one event handler, also the dataset approach has no extra benifit?

Comment: @Wimanicesir there is one handler, but multiple listeners in the OP code (one for each `li` element), additionally OP is querying `li` elements again inside the handler instead of using `target` property. Finally, `dataset` usage makes a HUGE difference in performance against jQuery methods. You can see the benchmark result [here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/210876).

Comment: You are right. I misread the selector and thought it was being set on the <ul>. The dataset usage is very interesting and something I didn't expect. Thanks for the explanation!